# Delete Sidebar via Database WordPress

Tags: database, wordpress

I need to delete some sidebar located in Appearence --> Widget.

What is the name of table in Database, that are stored ?

thanks

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58116/where-is-the-content-of-widgets-stored-in-mysql-table

Comment: I just see this post, but that is for widget inside sidebars. I need to find the sidebar list and delete what I'm interested in.

Comment: http://forum.bytesforall.com/showthread.php?t=3564
check this maybe help!

Comment: I use this and works : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140550/can-i-remove-a-widget-area-without-editing-code

Answer (score -1):

I think no need to go with DB, just do it by the following,

1. Drag & drop the widget in the wp-admin itself
   or
2. If its customized one, just delete the code for it in functions.php
   wp-content >> themes >> functions.php
   [the code like](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-dynamic-widget-ready-sidebars-in-wordpress/). But still you have doubt, dont worry to ask